# Crosstab in mysql

Tags: mysql, crosstab

i have this data

```
| car_name | year | price 
| Honda    | 2011 |  123
| Honda    | 2012 |  124
| Suzuki   | 2011 |  1234
| Suzuki   | 2012 |  1235
```

How im gonna change this into

```
| car_name | 2011 | 2012 |
| Honda    | 123  | 124
| Suzuki   | 1234 | 1235
```

please help me

Comment: Can you use PHP or some other language to create the query, or does it all have to be done in MySQL?

Comment: Actually I need all have to be done in MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can do the following:

```
SELECT car_name,
  max(case when year = '2011' then price ELSE 0 END) as `2011`,
  max(case when year = '2012' then price ELSE 0 END) as `2012`
FROM t
GROUP BY car_name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with a Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63e46/8)

Comment: more concise version: "select car_name,
  max(if(year = '2011', price, 0)) as `2011`,
  max(if(year = '2012', price, 0)) as `2012`
from t GROUP BY car_name"

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, here is your answer:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `year` FROM `table`";
$result = mysql_query($sql);


$sql2_select = "SELECT t1.`car_name`";
$sql2_from = "FROM `table` t1";

$i = 2;
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
  $year = $row[0];

  $sql2_select .= ", t{$i}.`price` AS `$year`"

  $sql_from .= " LEFT JOIN (SELECT `car_name`, `price` WHERE `year` = '$year') AS t{$i}";
  $sql_from .= " ON t1.`car_name` = t2.`car_name`";

  $i++;
}

$sql2 = $sql2_select . ' ' . $sql2_from . ' ' . "GROUP BY t1.car_name";

$result = mysql_query($sql2);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do crosstabs in MySQL is with subselects:

```
select car_name, 
(select price from t t2 where t2.car_name = t1.car_name and year = 2011) as '2011',
(select price from t t2 where t2.car_name = t1.car_name and year = 2012) as '2012'
from t t1
group by car_name
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63e46/11)

If you have more than one record per car per year, then sum(price).